# JSON: Show 3rd level content in Text Element (ReactJS/Native)

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, create-react-app

So I am trying to have a text element that displays a certain child from JSON (gotten using `fetch`). I have trying setting the response from fetch equal to `this.state.json` (declared in the constructor). Then I use a `Text` element with `this.state.json.current.name` (which is a valid child in the Airtime API), but I get an error saying `undefined is not an object` while evaluating `this.state.json.current.name`. I have tried making the function synchronous and asynchronous (I thought maybe the JSON wasn't loaded while text tried to be displayed), but nothing worked.

```js
  fetchJSON = async () => {
    fetch('http://IPADDRESS/api/live-info', {
      method: 'get',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      headers: {
         'Accept': 'application/json',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
  }).then((response) => {
       return response.json()
  }).then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({json: responseData})
        this.setState({isLoadedJSON: true})
        return responseData;
    })
  .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
  })
  }
```

then I just call `await this.fetchJSON()` in `componentWillMount()`.
For displaying text I just have `<Text>{this.state.json.current.name}</Text>`, but this doesn't work and I'm not sure if its a React issue or my issue. `this.state.json.env` works fine, but any further nested items, such as `this.state.json.current.name`, It displays undefined is not an object. I have also tried having an `isLoadedJSON` state and either an `if` or `while` before rendering, so it render a blank `View` while JSON is loading, but that then displays a blank View for ever.
Any thanks would be very highly appreciated.

```js
{
  "env": "production",
  "schedulerTime": "2018-02-15 13:37:50",
  "previous": {
    "name": "REDACTED",
    "starts": "2018-02-15 08:15:00",
    "ends": "2018-02-15 08:29:51.611",
    "type": "track"
  },
  "current": {
    "name": " - TVP",
    "starts": "2018-02-15 09:20:00",
    "ends": "2018-02-15 10:00:00",
    "media_item_played": true,
    "record": 0,
    "type": "track"
  },
  "next": {
    "name": "REDACTED",
    "starts": "2018-02-15 11:10:00",
    "ends": "2018-02-15 11:15:06.077",
    "type": "track"
  },
  "currentShow": [
    {
      "0": "2018-02-15 09:20:00",
      "1": "2018-02-15 10:00:00",
      "2": "REDACTED",
      "3": 33,
      "4": 273,
      "5": 0,
      "6": "",
      "7": "2018-02-15 09:20:00",
      "8": "2018-02-15 10:00:00",
      "start_timestamp": "2018-02-15 13:20:00",
      "end_timestamp": "2018-02-15 14:00:00",
      "name": "REDACTED",
      "id": 33,
      "instance_id": 273,
      "record": 0,
      "url": "",
      "starts": "2018-02-15 13:20:00",
      "ends": "2018-02-15 14:00:00"
    }
  ],
  "nextShow": [
    {
      "id": 23,
      "instance_id": 138,
      "name": "REDACTED",
      "url": "",
      "start_timestamp": "2018-02-15 15:10:00",
      "end_timestamp": "2018-02-15 15:20:00",
      "starts": "2018-02-15 15:10:00",
      "ends": "2018-02-15 15:20:00",
      "record": 0,
      "type": "show"
    }
  ],
  "timezone": "GST",
  "timezoneOffset": "14400",
  "AIRTIME_API_VERSION": "1.1"
}
```

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/zvhKT2mU)

Comment: Can you post the `responseData` ? And I would recommend you to call `fetchJSON` inside `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount`. More about that you can read on this nice article https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/

Comment: Edited for @Ionut

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probobly related to that when the render happens the response not being received and the json object on stat not yet set.

What you can do is to set a second state variable called like `name` and use that to display text.

**Example**

```
  fetchJSON = async () => {
    fetch('http://IPADDRESS/api/live-info', {
      method: 'get',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      headers: {
         'Accept': 'application/json',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
  }).then((response) => {
       return response.json()
  }).then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({
          json: responseData,
          name: responseData.current.name,
          isLoadedJSON: true
        });
        return responseData;
    })
  .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
  })
  }

  //...
  <Text>{this.state.name}</Text>
```

Comment: What about the weirdness when it comes this.state.json.env always working while no further nested objects work

Comment: @PhilipposSlicher I'm not really sure what causing that.

Comment: Yes, and no changes to the server providing the JSON either

Comment: @PhilipposSlicher can you please add more complete and recent version of an example of your code to the question please

Comment: Added PasteBin link

Comment: @PhilipposSlicher Couple of things I noticed on your code. On line 78 you have a extra bit of `strin` word. Secondly you are setting state directly on `startPlaying` and you should avoid that. and lastly you should know that `setState` is asynchronous and its not guarantied that `isLoadedJSON` is setting before `json` and `showName`. Second argument of `setState` is callback. You can use that. I don't know if your problem is related to those but you should fix these.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165396/discussion-between-philippos-slicher-and-bennygenel).

Answer (score 0):

What is actually happening here? The rendering triggers multiple times before the async request response. You can also check if the state has been set with the `json` by using `this.state.json&&` conditional rendering to check if `json` exists in `state`:

```js
class Testing extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    }
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    this.fetchJSON()     
  }
  fetchJSON() {
    fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/q6edh', {
        method: 'get',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }).then((response) => {
        return response.json()
      }).then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({
          json: responseData
        })
        this.setState({
          isLoadedJSON: true
        })
        //console.log(this.state);
        return responseData;
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      })
  }
  render() {
    return ( 
    <div>{this.state.json&& <p>And the name is: {this.state.json.current.name}</p>}</div>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render( <Testing/> ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```